# Replicability of a React Modal Form

Tags: react.js, jsx

I have a form type that I use several times throughout my project, and I've noticed that, rather than making the form replicable, I've just copied and pasted it a few times and made slight adjustments to it to fit each of my needs. Below is an example of what this form might look like:

```
const initValues = {
  email: '',
  password: ''
}

const initState = { values: initValues }

const LoginForm = ({ closeModal }) => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initState)
  const [fadeOut, setFadeOut] = useState(false)
  const { values, isLoading, error } = formState

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setFadeOut(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFadeOut(false)
      closeModal()
    }, 300)
  }

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    setFormState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      values: {
        ...prevState.values,
        [target.name]: target.value
      }
    }))
  }

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    setFormState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      isLoading: true
    }))
    try {
      await login(values)
      setFormState(initState)
      handleCloseModal()
    } catch (e) {
      setFormState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        isLoading: false,
        error: e.message
      }))
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.modalWrapper}>
      <div className={styles.modalBackground}>
        <div className={fadeOut ? styles.modalContainerExit : styles.modalContainer}>
          <div className={styles.closeButton}>
            <button onClick={handleCloseModal}> X </button>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.modalHeader}>
            <h1>Login Here</h1>
          </div>
          {error && (<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', color: 'red' }}>{error}</div>)}
          <div className={styles.modalBody}>
            <Input
              type='email'
              id='email'
              name='email'
              label='User Email'
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <Input
              type='password'
              id='password'
              name='password'
              label='User Password'
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.modalFooter}>
            {!isLoading ?
              <button className={buttonStyles.button} onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
              : <GlassLoader />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

(I didn't include the imports, as I didn't think that was necessary)
In each of my forms, the only things that I specifically change are the `initValues` object, the data types (specifically `type`, `id`, `name`, `label`, and `value`) for the `Input` tag, which is a custom component, and the type of function that is within the try block in the `onSubmit` function. (In this case it is the line `await login(values)`. The real big thing stopping me right now is the Input tag. I'd assume I'd just have to utilize arrays and map the values to the `Input` tags, but I wasn't sure if that would affect `handleInputChange` or `onSubmit` functions. Any advice is appreciated.